# Java result set to python cursor communication

Tags: python, django, jython

I am using PythonInterpretor to communicate to jython method from a java application. I am looking at sending a query result set to the method parameter, on the other end(Jython) the method expects Cursor(doj.db.backends). How can i typeCast or use any other existing methods?
I would like to pass the ResultSet from java to the method below.

In the Python I would like to do something like this

```
def method_name(cursor):
   for db_row in cursor:
        print db_row
        for col_name in cursor.description:
            if indexOf(cursor.description, col_name) != 0:
                //More things 
        //Return processed stuff
```